# Grabar un documento hecho mediante vfp en una unidad de red?

Tags: visual-foxpro

Tengo un programa hecho en visual foxpro 8 que exporta los datos de un cursor al excel y le quiero implementar algún comando para que el documento que se elabora en el programa se grabe en una unidad de red (ya se especifica en el código la dirección ip y la subcarpeta que contendrá al documento). Al probarlo tengo error ya que solo me deja grabar en un disco de la misma máquina por lo general el disco c
Lo siguiente es parte de como creo el objeto de excel y también unas variables para grabar el documento con un path específico

```
lcNombreArchivo = "C:\Documentos\info2024.xls"
lcNombreAux = "\\192.108.5.67\Documentos\info2024.xls
loArchivoExcel=createobject("Excel.application")
loArchivoExcel.APPLICATION.workbooks.ADD
....
....
....
....
....
loArchivoExcel.APPLICATION.activeworkbook.SAVEAS(lcNombreArchivo)
loArchivoExcel.APPLICATION.VISIBLE = .f.
loArchivoExcel.quit()
loArchivoExcel=.null.
```

e intente poniendo `copy file lcNombreArchivo to lcNombreAux` y es en este comando que se mostro un error ya que al parecer no reconoce el ip de la unidad de red. ¿Hay otra forma de hacer que se grabe en una unidad de red desde un procedimiento (función)?